# Proving a trigonometric identity (I'm a newbie)

Tags: trigonometry

Why does $$-\frac{\cos^2 x}{\sin x}= -\cos x\cot x?$$ Sorry for the dumb question.

Comment: break up the $-cos^2(x)$ into a product of 2 cosines. then use a trig definition.

Comment: Remember that $a^2 = aa$, and that $\frac{ab}{c} = \frac{a}{c}b = a\frac{b}{c}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at my comment above. 
$$\frac{-\cos^2(x)}{\sin(x)}\rightarrow \frac{-\cos(x)*{\color{red} {\cos(x)}}}{\color{red}{\sin(x)}} \rightarrow -\cos(x)\cot(x)$$

**hint** : $\cot(x)=\frac{cos(x)}{\sin(x)}$

Comment: Forgot a minus in the hint, :)

Comment: @Miguelgondu Hah, i was using that as a separator. I can see how that can me miss understood. I will replace with a colon, thanks!

Comment: Oh wow it makes sense now! I should've separated into two cosines *facepalm*

Comment: @user3709169 if you like the red for emphasis, check mine as accepted! Also, no need to facepalm, my first idea was wrong, this was my second attempt. Just something to get used to with math. Stay persistent!

Answer (score 3):

$-\frac{\cos^2(x)}{\sin(x)}=-\frac{\cos(x)\cdot \cos(x)}{\sin(x)}=-\cos(x)\cdot\frac{\cos(x)}{\sin(x)}=-\cos(x)\cot(x)$